# Presto left join SQL statement to return first match only

Tags: sql, presto

I know this question has been asked many times before, but for the life of me I am unable to figure this out.

I'm essentially trying to do a Left Join statement that is matching a Purchase Order number in table 1 with a Purchase order number in table 2. The issue is, since PO data is updated daily, it will return numerous rows from table 2 because there are different scenarios of a PO not being paid, canceled, etc.

Where I am running into issues is, my left join statement is returning multiple rows when joining against table 2.

Table 1 = T1

| POnum | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | I need help |
| 54321 | I need help |
| 78910 | I need help |

Table 2 = T2

| POnum | Date | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1/2/21 | ABC |
| 12345 | 1/2/21 | ABC |
| 12345 | 1/2/21 | ABC |
| 54321 | 1/1/21 | CBD |
| 54321 | 1/1/21 | CBD |
| 54321 | 1/1/21 | CBD |
| 78910 | 1/5/21 | GED |
| 78910 | 1/5/21 | GED |
| 78910 | 1/5/21 | GED |

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Select
    t1.POnum, T2.Vendor
From
    Table 1 as T1
Left Join
    Table 2 as T2 On T1.POnum = T2.POnum
```

As you will note, in Table 2 the PO number 12345 has 3 rows with the same exact date.

The ending result should essentially look like the following:

| T1.POnum | T2.Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC |
| 54321 | CBD |
| 78910 | GED |

Answer (score 0):

where in query you are using the date from Table T2 ?
you have not used any where clause also in query, it means no condition is required.
The result you need can be achieved directly without any join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PONUM, VENDOR FROM Table2;
```

Let me know in case anything is missing here.